# Node.js check options

Tags: node.js, powershell

the `--check` command line option should check (for errors) the file without executing it, but it does not work.

It worked once or twice but this is not the case now, am I missing something or this is not the right syntax maybe?

TESTED on windows 10 / PowerShell (with Administrator privileges)

```
--- PowerShell command line
$ > node --check index.js                           // doesn't do anything (no error thrown)
$ > node -c index.js                                // doesn't do anything (no error thrown)
$ > node index.js --check                           // executes the file (prints 'module executed!' and throws a ReferenceError) 
$ > node index.js -c                                // executes the file (prints 'module executed!' and throws a ReferenceError)
```

```
--- index.js file 
console.log( 'module executed!' );

myRefferenceError;                                  // ReferenceError
```

Comment: It does throw the error right?. (Consider last two given commands)

Comment: Yes it does but also runs the file, so basically ignores the ```--check``` and ```-c``` options when placed after the ```node index.js```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Certainly, the `node --check index.js` (or) `node -c index.js` is the correct way to execute the flag.

However, as per the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_c_check), it looks like the flag will check only syntactical errors and won't check beyond that which is was happening in your case.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yep you're right the ```--check``` option only check for syntactical errors (I knew I missed something thanks)

Comment: Np @PallArpad, It was a refresher for me also